# add_rewrite_url get parameters are empty

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, get

I used add_rewrite_rule to redirect a nice URL to the right page.
This is the rule:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?pagename=auto&id=1234', 'top' );
```

So if I go to the following URL: website.com/cars/brand/model/car/1234 It wil go to the page with pagename auto.

On this page is a shortcode that needs to get this id. If I echo $_GET['pagename'] it prints 'auto'. But if I print $_GET['id'] it contains nothing. Why can't I get that value in the shortcode??

This rule works fine:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?pagename=auto&id=' . $_GET['id'], 'top' );
```

But I want something like this:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?pagename=auto&id=$matches[5]', 'top' );
```

I don't know why the $matches is empty.

Complete code:

```
function redirectUrls() {
    flush_rewrite_rules();
    add_rewrite_rule('^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?pagename=auto&id=1234', 'top' );
}
add_action('init', 'redirectUrls');
```

I put this code in my plugin

**EDIT (ANSWER)**
Oke I've used this tutorial and it works: http://www.janes.co.za/wordpress-permalinks-and-custom-_get-variables/

I also used the answer of @Sacroma

```
function add_query_vars($aVars) {
    $aVars[] = "id";    // represents the name of the product category as shown in the URL
    return $aVars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');

function add_rewrite_rules($aRules) {
    $aNewRules = array('^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=auto&id=$matches[5]');
    $aRules = $aNewRules + $aRules;
    return $aRules;
}

add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'add_rewrite_rules');
```

Now I can use the get_query_var("id")

Comment: Guessing it's just for testing, but make sure to remove flush_rewrite_rules() in production.

Comment: Are the first four regex expressions needed? If you aren't matching anything they should be static. *ie* `add_rewrite_rule('^cars/brand/model/car/([^/]*)/?','index.php?pagename=auto&id=$matches[]', 'top' );` otherwise you could literally type anything in those spaces to match the rewrite rule.

Comment: I know. For now it's ok. It is in a plugin. so you don't know what the page will be called. now it could be occassions/bmw/x1/bmwx1/1234 but it could also be cars/audi/a3/4212

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for `get_query_var("id")` it retrieves the GET parameter from a pretty url.

See the codex for more details.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var

Comment: This didn't work. But I've found something to get this to work. Thanks

Comment: The issue was that wordpress didn't recognise the id tag, this is because it hadn't been registered. You should use `add_rewrite_tag()` for any unregistered rewrite tags you want to use in the url. https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag

Comment: I'd probably call it car_id rather than id, just to make sure it doesn't conflict with other tags.

Comment: Thanks this looks even better I think